# Codeigniter will not load language

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello i have problem with Codeigniter language class.

I follow this guide :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

I create test controller

I create test_lang.php inside app/language/english

I set english language in config file

**My controller :**

```
<?php

    class Test extends MX_Controller
    {
        public $data;

        function __construct() 
        {
            $this->load->helper('language');
            $this->load->lang('test');
        }

        function index() {

            $this->data['title'] = $this->lang->line("test");

            $this->load->view('test',  $this->data);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**Application/language/english/test_lang.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$lang['test'] = 'This form post did not pass our security checks.';


?>
```

**Views :**

```
<?php

echo $title;
?>
```

And i have blanko page. No result, nothing is heppenging.

I try directly in views to put **echo $this->lang->line("test");** and again nothing.

What i do wrong? Any1 can tell me how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load the language file by using `$this->lang->load('test');` instead of `$this->load->lang('test');`.

**Update:**

There are some mistakes in your controller, first `__constructor()` must be changed to `__construct()`. Second, you should call the parent `__construct()` method after overriding:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens. It's still the same.

Comment: Nothing happens again. IDK wtf is problem. am so confused, all work good only language.

Comment: Check this: When i put ***$this->lang->load('test');*** and ***$this->load->helper('language');***  in index() method all work good. but in ***__constructor()**** dont work

Comment: Now is fixed. Thanks bro for helping