# Changed controller load locations, and can't use any functions in controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

By default, as many of you probably know, codeigniter loads controllers from `application/controllers (URI Segment 0)`. Well... I changed it so that it loads them fom `application/modules/(URI Segment 0)/controllers/(URI Segment 1 / not set: URI Segment 0)`. Up to here it all works fine, but when I create a controller, I cannot use any of the default function as `$this->load` or etc... Example:

```
/**
* Home Controller Class
*/
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Testing...";
    }
}
```

This example would always result in an error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/home.php
>
> Line Number: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know how you exactly changed the Controller location.

But when you extend the `CI_Controller`, and you use a constructor method, you need to execute the parent's `__construct()` method at first, as follows:

```php
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        /* Execute the CI_Controller constructor */
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }
}
```

That's because your **local** constructor will be **overriding** the one in the **parent** controller class. So you need to manually call it.

[CodeIgniter Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors).

**Similar topics on SO:**

- [Undefined $load property error after upgrading CodeIgniter 1.7 to 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320446/undefined-load-property-error-after-upgrading-codeigniter-1-7-to-2-1/18321751#18321751)
- [Codeigniter will not load language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084284/codeigniter-will-not-load-language/18084318#18084318)